# How can I assign a new variable value based on text selection in .liquid

Tags: shopify

Ok so I have a table with 2 columns. In the left column I have a 4 anchor links say 'FAQS', 'HOW TO', 'LIKES', 'OTHER'. each of these links have there own page. What I want to do is populate the right column with the page content based on what the user selected.

Below is the code for my page. please help

```
<table width = 100% border = "1px">
<tr><h3>Test</h3></tr>
<tr>
<td width = 20% border = "1px" valign = "top">
<a>FAQS</a>
<a>HOW TO</a>
<a>LIKES</a>
<a>other</a>
</td>
<td width = 80% border = "1px">
{% assign infopg = 2 %}

{% case infopg %} 
{% when 1 %} 
{{ pages.faqs.content }}
{% when 2 %} 
{{ pages.how-to-shop.content }}
{% when 3 %} 
{{ pages.likes.content }}  
{% else %} 
{{ pages.other.content }}
{% endcase %} 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the front end with the back end. Liquid is used to render your HTML. If you want to react to some customer clicks, like selecting a menu, you need to use Javascript, not Liquid. You are free to render all the content you need with Liquid, so that Javascript clicks show/hide things, but the answer to your question is "Use Javaascript".

Comment: Dude! Thank you so much for your help. I finally got what I wanted to work:)